# Disable splitting of screen when dragging/resizing window

Tags: windows-7

[image]

When I drag or resize a window the screen splits into four parts! I cannot for the love of God find out how to disable this annoying feature. Can anyone help me?

"Tick the check box for Prevent Windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen with the mouse under “Make it easier to manage windows” section."

This is done. The problem is happening as soon as I pull on a window.

Comment: Looks like a 3rd party desktop manager. Look in add/remove programs, and play with MSConfig.

Comment: You were absolutely right. Dell display manager in my case.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I figured I'd get you to confirm first.   I'll throw it into an answer to make it all official-like. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a 3rd party desktop manager.

Check in Add/Remove Programs, and play with MSConfig.exe to determine what it may be.

Then uninstall it. :)